# Python split a set of characters by pointing a particular string

Tags: python

The input I got:

```
data = 'VALUE - TRIP NAME: LOSANGELES45 US - UNITED STATES-9876543210:TRIP NAME: LOSANGELES45'
```

Expected output:

```
result = LOSANGELES45
```

I need to print out the LOSANGELES45 from the above string. The TRIP NAME will be a static value and the LOSEANGELES45 will be a dynamic value. How can I achieve this in python 3.7?

Comment: What is the *rule that tells you*, for this particular string, that `LOSANGELES45` is the correct result, and not any other part of the string?

Comment: Well, It is set like in that way.@KarlKnechtel

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't tell me anything useful at all. Say for example that I said instead that the answer should be `LES45 US - UNI`. *Why am I wrong*? When you say "The TRIP NAME will be a static value", *why is that relevant*? Does that text help you figure out where to look in the string for the correct result? Exactly how? And exactly how do you decide when the correct result *ends*? Why is the correct answer not `LOSANGELES45 US - UNITED STATES`? It is only possible to solve programming problems if the actual problem is known.

Comment: I understood your question well@Suji .Looks like split() worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.split("TRIP NAME: ")[1].split(" ")[0]
```

This splits your string at 'TRIP NAME: ', selects the second element (from LOSANGELES45 onward), splits the string again after a space and selects the first element.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the below split and select the method. It might help for given problem

```
data.split(' ')[-1]
```

as 'LOSEANGELES45' is always in last. by [-1], it always selects the last splited string